# python エラー　単語を入力し、そこに含まれる母音を出力したい

Tags: python

リストに母音を指定し、単語に含まれている母音を順次出力できるようにしました。出力される母音の重複を避けるため、printによって出力した母音はdel関数でリストから消去しました。以下のコードを試してみたところ、うまくいく場合とうまくいかない場合があります。

- うまくいった例：
  aaaaaa（aと出力された）,python（oと出力された）
- うまくいかなかった例：
  aaaiiiiii（aiiiと出力された）

エラー時には以下のメッセージが表示されましたが、何が原因かわからないです。

みなさんの力を借りたいです。よろしくお願いします。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
del found[2]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

**ソースコード:**

```
word=input("単語を入力してください")
found=["a","e","i","u","o"]

for w in word:
    if w in found:
        print(w)
        if w=="a":
            del found[0]

        elif w=="e":
            del found[1]
        elif w=="i":
            del found[2]
        elif w=="u":
            del found[3]
        elif w=="o":
            del found[4]
        else:
            pass
            
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: 視点を変えて `found` から見ればよいのではないでしょうか。`print([x for x in found if x in word])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> エラー時には以下のメッセージが表示されましたが、何が原因かわからないです。

delで削除すると、要素の位置が変わってしまい、2回目以降の`del found[2]`で'i'ではない別の要素が削除されてしまいます。続けているうちにfoundの範囲外の要素を削除しようとしてエラーが発生します。

具体的な動きは次のようになります。

- 最初にaが見つかったとき`del found[0]`が実行され、foundの値が`['e', 'i', 'u', 'o']`となります。
- 次にiが見つかったとき`del found[2]`が実行され、foundの値が`['e', 'i', 'o']`となりますが'i'の要素は残ったままです。
- 次に'i'が見つかったときfoundは`['e', 'i']となります。 その次に'i'が見つかったとき、`del found[2]`が実行されますが、found[2]は存在しないため、エラーが発生します。

delの代わりに`found.remove(w)`を実行すれば問題は解消します。

Comment: 理解しました。ありがとうございます